# Preventing symetric pairs in datalog logic

Tags: datalog, clingo

I am running a datalog rule with `clingo` in `jupyter notebook` against graph nodes checking for nodes that share the same direct ancestor as follows:

```
ancestor(A,B).
ancestor(A,C).
sibs(X,Y) = ancestor(Z,X), ancestor(Z,Y), X!=Y.
```

This gives me 2 simetric pairs namely

```
sibs(B,C) sibs(C,B)
```

How to I restrict the generation of sibs to only have either of these two results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to track down the issue.  To ensure you do not return both results change this:

`sibs(X,Y) = ancestor(Z,X), ancestor(Z,Y), X!=Y.`

to this:

`sibs(X,Y) = ancestor(Z,X), ancestor(Z,Y), X<Y.`